# How do I plot E8 (Exceptional Lie Group order 8) in 2D?

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry

For the last week or so I have been struggling to find a resource that will allow me to make something like [the 2D petrie polygon diagrams in this article](https://wikimili.com/en/Petrie_polygon#24-cell_t0_F4.svg).

My main trouble is finding out what the rules are for the edge and node connections.

I.e. in this plot, is there a simple way to make the image from scratch (even if it not fully representative of the bigger theory behind it)?

[image: E8]

Any help is massively appreciated!

K

Comment: You may have more success with this question on the math site. If you want to try that, flag this question and ask one of the moderators to move the question there.

Comment: @templatetypedef yep I tried there and will update if I get anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem!

[e8](https://github.com/stackedflows/Main-Site/blob/main/E8.pdf)

```
// to run
//  clink -c Ex8
// ./Ex8
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "dislin.h"

// method to generate all permutations of a set with repeated elements: 
the root system
float root_sys[240][8];

int count = 0;

/// checks elements in root system to see if they should be permuted
int shouldSwap(float base[], int start, int curr)
{
    for (int i = start; i < curr; i++)
        if (base[i] == base[curr])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

/// performs permutations of root system
void permutations(float base[], int index, int n)
{
    if (index >= n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
          root_sys[count][i] = base[i];
        }
        count++;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = index; i < n; i++) {
        int check = shouldSwap(base, index, i);
        if (check) {
            float temp_0 = base[index];
            float temp_1 = base[i];
            base[index] = temp_1;
            base[i] = temp_0;
            permutations(base, index + 1, n);
            float temp_2 = base[index];
            float temp_3 = base[i];
            base[index] = temp_3;
            base[i] = temp_2;
        }
    }
}

// function to list all distances from one node to others
float inner_product(float * vect_0, float * vect_1){
  float sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    sum = sum + ((vect_0[i] - vect_1[i]) * (vect_0[i] - vect_1[i]));
  }return sum;
}

/// inner product funtion 
float inner_product_plus(float * vect_0, float * vect_1){
  float sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    sum = sum + (vect_0[i] * vect_1[i]);
  }return sum;
}

int main(void){

  // base vector permutations of E8 root system
  float base_sys[8][8] = {
    {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0.5,0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5},
    {0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5},
    {0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,-0.5,-0.5},
    {0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5},
    {-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5}
  };

  //permute the base vectors
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    permutations(base_sys[i],0,8);
  }

  //calculating distances between all roots, outputting correspondence matrix
  int distance_matrix[240][240];
  for(int i = 0; i < 240; i++){
    int dist_m = 100;
    for(int ii = 0; ii < 240; ii++){
      float dist = inner_product(root_sys[i], root_sys[ii]);
      if(dist == 2){ //connecting distance in E8
        distance_matrix[i][ii] = 1;
      }else{distance_matrix[i][ii] == 0;};
    }
  }

  //use another program to calculate eigenvectors of root system . . . after some fiddling, these vectors appear
  float re[8] = {0.438217070641, 0.205187681291,
     0.36459828198, 0.0124511903657,
     -0.0124511903657, -0.36459828198,
     -0.205187681291, -0.67645247517};

  float im[8] = {-0.118465163028, 0.404927414852,
    0.581970822973, 0.264896157496,
    0.501826483552, 0.345040496917,
    0.167997088796, 0.118465163028};

  //define co-ordinate system for relevent points
  float rings_x[240];
  float rings_y[240];

  //decide on which points belong to the system
  for(int i = 0; i < 240; i++){
    float current_point[8];
    for(int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++){
      current_point[ii] = root_sys[i][ii];
    }
    rings_x[i] = inner_product_plus(current_point, re);
    rings_y[i] = inner_product_plus(current_point, im);
  }

  //graph the system using DISLIN library
  scrmod("revers");
  setpag("da4l");
  metafl("cons");
  disini();
  graf(-1.2, 1.2, -1.2, 1.2, -1.2, 1.2, -1.2, 1);
  
  // a connection appears depending on the previously calculated distance matrix
  for(int i = 0; i < 240; i++){
    for(int ii = 0; ii < 240; ii++){
      int connect = distance_matrix[i][ii];
      if(connect == 1){
        rline(rings_x[i], rings_y[i], rings_x[ii], rings_y[ii]);
        distance_matrix[ii][i] = 0;
      }else{continue;}
    }
  }

  // More DISLIN functions
  titlin("E8", 1);

  name("R-axis", "x");
  name("I-axis", "y");

  marker(21);
  hsymbl(15);

  qplsca(rings_x, rings_y, 240);

  return 0;
}
```

Extra points to anyone who can explain how to rotate the 2d plot to create a 3-d animation of this object